# Как и где писать техническую документацию

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Существуют библиотеки C#, нужно составить документацию для коллег по их использованию. Как и где лучше это делать? т.к. пробовал в word не очень удобно, натолкните на какую-нибудь статью

Comment: [Creating documentation in C# using Visual Studio and Sandcastle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2014/04/22/creating-documentation-in-c-using-visual-studio-and-sandcastle/)

Comment: Интересная статья: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/02/21/vs-dotnet-code-documentation-tools-roundup.aspx